# How to prevent Pycharm from formatting a line of HTML code

Tags: python, html, xml, pycharm, odoo

I have a single line of HTML code in Pycharm

```
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"><t t-esc="message"/></textarea>
```

This is processed in Odoo with lxml. But I don't want that Pycharm reformats the code thus:

```
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Message">
    <t t-esc="message"/>
</textarea>
```

because I get extra spaces around the text. Is there a way to tell Pycharm not to reformat this specific line?

Comment: may be this link is help you https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/reformatting-source-code.html

Comment: if you indentation problem then see this link https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/changing-indentation.html

Comment: No, not indentation problem. With the link you provided I just posted the answer. @JainikPatel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So as mentioned [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/code-style.html#d583750e334), I used:

```
<!--@formatter:off-->
<!-- Some code -->
<!--@formatter:on-->
```

But I had to turn on formatter markers in Settings > Editor > Code Style

Thanks Jainik Patel.